# What is the purpose of a listener class in a large project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, listener, actionlistener

I'm confused about what listener classes do. For example, in this project there is a listener class referenced as so:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Is it as the name implies, just listening for actions to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest reviewing the chapter on "Application Lifecycle Events" from the Servlet specification.

Depending on which version you're using, here are the corresponding chapters and links to the docs:

- [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html) : Chapter 11
- [Servlet 2.5](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/) : Chapter 10
- [Servlet 2.4](http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/) : Chapter 10

Listeners are used to be notified of events to web applications, including state changes in the `ServletContext`, `HttpSession`, and `ServletRequest` objects. By implementing predefined listener interfaces ([`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), [`javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html), etc.), the servlet container will notify you of certain events that are happening in your application. They have a lot of potential uses, such as performing one-time application setup and shutdown tasks, intercepting requests to perform logging, tracking HTTP session use, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Listener Classes get notified on selected events, such as starting up the application or creating a new Session.

Listener Classes :

> These are simple Java classes which implement one of the two following
>   interfaces :
>
> - `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`
> - `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`
>
> If you want your class to listen for application startup and shutdown
>   events then implement `ServletContextListener` interface. If you want
>   your class to listen for session creation and invalidation events then
>   implement `HttpSessionListener` interface.

[Source](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001111901&page=1)

Comment: `ServletContextListener` usually react on startup and shutdown of the web application and trigger any necessary initialization of necessary objects. `HttpSessionListener` usually react on users logging on to the application and do per-user initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Yes exactly they are listening for some action todo, for example if its contextloaderlistener then it will listen to context loading event and there are many stuff that we can do at such event so these are made for that

Answer (score 2):

More generally, a listener is the observer/subscriber side in the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The server/framework side provides you with a means to be notified of some event and therefore give you a chance to do your actions.

And it not necessarily must be "a large project". Listeners come handy even in the smaller ones :).

Comment: @VineetReynolds Thanks, "client" was awkward here. BTW, how can I see what was exactly edited, supposing that you hadn't notified me? Is there a "history" button I can't see because of my low rep?